# What is $\sup\limits_{f \in \mathscr F} \int_{1}^{3} \frac {f(x)} {x}\ dx\ $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $\mathscr F$ be the set of all continuous functions $f : [1,3] \longrightarrow [-1,1]$ such that $\int_{1}^{3} f(x)\ dx = 0.$ Find the value of $$\sup\limits_{f \in \mathscr F} \int_{1}^{3} \frac {f(x)} {x}\ dx.$$

This is one of the PhD screening test  questions I have recently come across which I cannot able to answer. Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for investing your valuable time on my question.

Comment: This is a Putnam problem

Comment: @FShrike$:$ This question appears in NBHM exam in 2023 in India.

Comment: @FShrike$:$ Please have a look at here https://www.imsc.res.in/~nbhm/qp/

Comment: I've also seen a very similar problem in a Putnam exam. An intuitive solution would be to consider what happens to the functional as $f$ goes to $\{ 1, x \in [1, 1.5],\ -1,\  x\in (1.5,3] \}$.

Comment: @kongram$:$ Do you mean $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in \left [1, 2 - \frac 1 n \right ] \\ n \left (2 - x \right ) & x \in \left (2 - \frac 1 n, 2 + \frac 1 n \right ] \\ -1 & x \in \left (2 + \frac 1 n, 3 \right ] \end{cases}$$

Comment: The value of the integral $$\int_{1}^{3} \frac {f_n (x)} {x}\ dx = (2n + 1) \ln \left ( 2 + \frac 1 n \right ) - (2n - 1) \ln \left (2 - \frac 1 n \right ) - 2 - \ln 3.$$

Comment: The limit of the right hand sequence is $\ln \left (\frac 4 3 \right )$ as shown by wolfram. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit+%282n+%2B+1%29+ln+%282+%2B+1%2Fn%29+-+%282n+-+1%29+ln+%282+-+1%2Fn%29+-+2+-+ln+3+as+n-%3Einfinity

Comment: An idea is to look at the supremum taken over all polynomials. Then both integrals involved will become scalar functions of the coefficients. And since the polynomials are dense in the continous functions, the supremum will be the same. Only problem is to translate the remaining boundary condition into some nice function of the coefficients.